# How we can execute multiple function at same time or we can use multiple function in environmental variables in AWS lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Suppose I have created two method read and insert in my springboot application( read method will fetch data from dynamodb while insert method will insert data into the database).And in spingboot application.property I have define spring.cloud.function.definiton=read;insert but in AWS lambda in environmental vairable I can only define one method at a time(either read or insert but not at same time),I am stuck at that point, so for resolving this problem I have create API using AWS API gateway but for read and insert API I have created two different lambda function,So is there any way either we can define both read and insert method parallel in aws environmental variable or using single lambda function we can hit API for both method????

Comment: You are trying to do two different operations, you should have two different lambdas.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/  -- Here it is mentioned that we can replace environment variable with stage variable, is there any way to replace it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java sdk and invoke the lambda with a param.
The lambda can have your read and write functions inside and when you invoke it, just pass a param to indicate whether the lambda should run in which mode you like.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-lambda.html#invoke-function

You don't need an API Gateway.

Comment: Can you please explain with examples

Comment: The link has examples but here is the first part to set up the variable: AWSLambda awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();

Then  comes the lambda invoke          invokeResult = awsLambda.invoke(invokeRequest);

            String ans = new String(invokeResult.getPayload().array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);  Then that getPayload has the result of the lambda call. You will have to figure out first how to invoke the lambda and then to pass a parameter to.